# Facebook share button missing from company page

Tags: facebook, facebook-pages, sharing

I manage a company page on Facebook (https://facebook.com/emotionathletes). I am able to share it to my friends from my computer browser ("Partilhar" is "Share" in Portuguese):

[image: Facebook page seen from my account]

A follower of the page wants to share it to their friends from the Android app. They click the ellipsis button on the page:

[image: Facebook page seen from a follower's account]

and that share button is missing:

[image: Facebook page seen from another account with missing share button]

From the same phone and account on another page, the "share" button is present, along with "Get directions" and "Visit" (which do not apply to my page):

[image: Other page with Share button]

And after clicking on "share", the options are "post", "messenger", and "copy link":

[image: Other page with result of "Share" button]

I could not find in the settings of my page anything related to this apparent prevention of followers to share the page. Why does this happen and how can I allow followers to share the page?

Comment: Hi Could you manage to solve your issue I am experiencing the same issue, I think it has something to to with the accounts privacy settings but not sure what.

Comment: No, I could not manage to solve the issue. I contacted Facebook Support several times, got promises but no answer.

Comment: I see the old type of Pages it works but if I create new Pages it does not work, maybe they removed it..

Comment: I also moved to the New Pages Experience and confirm that the button is still missing.